Azure Data Factory fails to connect to a SQL Server on-premise
We have a pipeline that executes every day at 03:00 AM, copying data from a Dataverse database (Dynamics CRM) to an on-premise SQL Server. Some days it works perfectly, while other days it fails with the following error:

Type=Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException,
Message=Failed to connect to Dataverse,
Source=Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client,''
Type=System.Exception,
Message=ExternalTokenManagement Authentication Requested but not configured correctly.
Source=Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client,''
Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''
Type=System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,
Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
Source=mscorlib,'' Type=System.Net.WebException,
Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source=System,''  Type=System.IO.IOException,
Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.,
Source=System,''   Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,
Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

We have checked the connections individually to both Dataverse and SQL Server, and they work fine. The problem only occurs when the pipeline is executed.
We have also added the following IP addresses to the firewall of the server in which the SQL Server is installed, but the issue persists:
{
      "name": "DataFactory.BrazilSouth",
      "id": "DataFactory.BrazilSouth",
      "properties": {
        "changeNumber": 6,
        "region": "brazilsouth",
        "regionId": 9,
        "platform": "Azure",
        "systemService": "DataFactory",
        "addressPrefixes": [
          "4.203.145.160/27",
          "20.206.179.144/29",
          "191.233.205.160/28",
          "191.234.137.32/29",
          "191.234.142.64/26",
          "191.234.143.0/24",
          "191.234.149.0/28",
          "191.234.157.0/28",
          "191.235.224.128/25",
          "191.235.225.0/26",
          "2603:1050:6:1::480/121",
          "2603:1050:6:1::500/122",
          "2603:1050:6:1::700/121",
          "2603:1050:6:1::780/122",
          "2603:1050:6:402::330/124",
          "2603:1050:6:802::210/124",
          "2603:1050:6:c02::210/124"
        ],
        "networkFeatures": [
          "API",
          "NSG"
        ]
      }
    }

Our Azure service is hosted in Brazil South.


Type=Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException,
Message=Failed to connect to Dataverse,
Source=Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client,''
Type=System.Exception,
Message=ExternalTokenManagement Authentication Requested but not configured correctly.

The error you are facing from Dataverse side, ADF is unable to establish a connection with Dataverse.
Here are few reasons and solutions you can try to avoid this error:

Using the wrong authentication method : Verify your ADF pipeline's authentication settings once. Make that the credentials are proper and that you're using the right method (service principal). For comprehensive configuration instructions, consult the official documentation


If your tenant and user is configured in Microsoft Entra ID for conditional access and/or Multi-Factor Authentication is required, you will not be able to use Office 365 Authentication type. For those situations, you must use a Microsoft Entra service principal authentication.


Problems with Network Connectivity :  Make sure that no network security groups (NSGs) or firewalls are preventing ADF and Dataverse from communicating with one another. For debugging purposes, you may need to temporarily permit traffic on the appropriate ports (443 for HTTPS).

